# PersistenceException on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Suddenly, our app is throwing this error:

Error
Exception: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Transaction failed to flush; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Transaction failed to flush

I notice that the "Datastore Read Operations" has reached 100%. Could this be issue related to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I notice that the "Datastore Read Operations" has reached 100%. Could this be issue related to this?
```

When Spring tries to pass the control to the persisting operations controller, it must flush to persist everything in the transction to the database, but when the DB cn' accept them anymore, because i reached the limit: `Datastore Read Operations" has reached 100%`, it will throw this exception.

I assume you have some limited space in DB there? Maybe you just run out of space?